# Highcharts - Exporting with credits in IE 7/8

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm having problems getting the credits to show up properly on my exported Highcharts chart in IE 7 and 8. I'm using a custom Highcharts module (https://github.com/imclem/Highcharts-export-module-asp.net), and it's causing the y-axis to be displayed down in the credits section.

Taking a look at the demos on the Highcharts page, I'm not convinced the export module is at fault. All of the examples found [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting) set credits to disabled. If I change the JSFiddle to enable credits, exporting in IE 7 and 8 still leaves out the credits altogether (works fine in Chrome, Firefox, and IE 9+). For example, if you enable credits on [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/exporting/filename/), run that on IE 7 or 8, and export the chart to a PNG, you should see the credits are missing from the image.

Here's the JavaScript for the example with credits enabled:

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: true
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    }],

    exporting: {
        filename: 'custom-file-name'
    }

});
```

});

This leads me to believe this is a known issue, but I have not been able to find mention of it anywhere. Should the credits work when exporting to an image?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known issue with 3.0.7 version. It's already fixed on master branch:

```
<script src="http://github.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

Fix will be included in next release, within a few weeks (3-4).